# How to change FBLoginView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, ios6

I simply need to increase the width of Facebook FBLoginView.

Hence, I try to change the frame width, but it seems it have no effect.

I can see x,y can be changed, but not width ,why?

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

      CGRect usableBounds =[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
    // Create Login View so that the app will be granted "status_update" permission.
    FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];


    loginview.frame= CGRectOffset(loginview.frame,
                                      ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-loginview.frame.size.width)/2,
                                      ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-loginview.frame.size.height)/2 -50);


    loginview.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [loginview sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the [loginView sizeToFit]; method to get rid of the view clipping.